# Send message on email LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel

The error I get

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ecolor\resources\views\ecolors\emailStr.blade.php)

The code I use

```
return htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8', $doubleEncode);
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: code html to exit page

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style="width: 50%; margin: auto;">
<p style="font-size:20px">От кого:
<p style="font-weight:600;">{{$name}} {{$surname}} {{$email}} {{$phone}}</p>
</p>
<div style="border: 1px solid;">
{{$message}}
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: you are passing and object instead of string variable..share the code please

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. You should pass a string but instead you pass an object. print_r your variable to see what's there, and access the field you want to

Comment: @dorinex98 please share your complete code by editing your question, not in comments.

Comment: general edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to echo a variable called `$message` in your blade.But it is not actual the `$message` variable you passed to the view. It is a laravel made `$message` variable which is a object.That's why error shown.

A `$message` variable is always passed to e-mail views, and allows the inline embedding of attachments. So, it is best to avoid passing a message variable in your view payload.

Simply rename `$message` to `$somethingelse` and everything should work perfectly fine again!

more details : https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail#embedding-inline-attachments

Comment: @dorinex98, did you understand my answer ?